# Changing a Contract Status to expired

Tags: maximo, contracts

I am currently doing some research regarding the Contracts module of `Maximo`. My question is as follows.

How do you change a contract status to expired in `Maximo`?

We are currently using versions `7.508` and `7.602`.

From what I have found so far it is possible that this may only be done via an escalation, but it would be nice if anyone could enlighten me as to another method. I was hoping that a contract would automatically change to expired status once the current date has surpassed the expiration date, but had no such luck.